# Trying to download zip file from drive to instance in colab hits quota limit

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to download the zip file dataset from drive using

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
!cp "/content/drive/Shared Drives/infinity-drive/datasets/coco.zip" ./data
```

I get the error that one of the quota limits is exceeded for 3 days in consecutively and file copying ends in I/O error.
I went over all the solutions. File size is 18GB. Although I could not understand the directive
`Use drive.google.com to download the file.`. What does it have to do with triggering limis in colab? For people trying to download file to colab instance and then to their local machine? Any way/

The file is in archive format.
The folder it is in has no any other files in it.
The file is private, although I am not the manager of the shared drive.

I am baffled at exactly which quota I am hitting. It does not say to me but I am 99% sure I should not be hitting any considering I can download the entire thing to my local machine. I can't keep track of exactly what is happening because even within the same day, it is able to copy about 3-5 GB of the file(even the file size is changing).

Comment: i cant seem to reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in colab/Drive integration, and is tracked in [#1607](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1607). See this [comment](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1607#issuecomment-701704057) for workarounds.

Comment: Yes can't believe I missed that. gdown and pydrive API's both worked for me.